# Palabra correcta para describir la "acción de solicitar"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

¿Cuál es la palabra correcta para describir la "acción de solicitar", según la RAE? ¿"Solicitación"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí, [según la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/solicitaci%C3%B3n), *solicitación* tiene como su único significado la *"acción de solicitar"*.

Comment: Creo que "solicitud" es más apropiado.

Comment: @Jorge a mi también me suena mejor, pero la RAE no tiene *"acción de solicitar"* como un significado de *"solicitud"* : http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=solicitud

Comment: @Caesar puede que no estuviese en la 22.ª ed. pero está tal cual en la 23.ª «acción y efecto de solicitar»

Answer (score 8):

Probablemente dependa del contexto, tanto regional como del texto mismo.

Derivado del verbo solicitar es más utilizada (al menos en Chile):

> [Solicitud](http://www.rae.es/solicitud)

Otra opción puede ser:

> [Petición](http://www.rae.es/peticion)

Comment: En Espana, también es mucho màs usada solicitud. De hecho solicitaciòn nunca la oì. Pero es cierto que la RAE lo dice.

Comment: Jejeje, en realidad yo tampoco había visto ni escuchado "solicitación", pero siguiendo casos como "asignación", "emisión", "redención", etc., parecía lo más lógico.

Comment: solicitacion ... parece un nombre de monja xDD

Answer (score 2):

Aunque admitido por la RAE, no creo que en España se use nunca la palabra  «solicitación». Si la escuchara pensaría inmediatamente que el interlocutor no es español. Lo normal sería emplear «solicitud» o «petición», o algún sinónimo en determinados contextos administrativos o jurídicos («demanda», «apelación», «instancia», «reclamación», etc.).

Comment: Tu respuesta también relevante para el caso de México.